# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

can anyone spot the issue in my code? for some reason its not reading the data. ive tried using question marks before the period but thats not the correct solution because im still getting an error. the code is below

```
   import { useState } from "react"

const TodoItem = ({ todo, removeTodo, editTodo, toggle }) => {

    const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState(todo.title)

    const handleTodoChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(todo.completed === true) {
            setNewTodo(todo.title)
        } else {
            todo.title = ''
            setNewTodo(e.target.value)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
           <input 
           value={ todo.title === '' ? newTodo : todo.title }
           type="text" 
           className={ todo.completed ? 'line-through text-red-300' : ''} 
           onChange={handleTodoChange}
           />
           <div>
           <button 
           onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}>
             <svg id ='i' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" 
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
                stroke="currentColor">
        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16" />
            </svg></button>

            <button onClick = {() => editTodo(todo, newTodo)}>
            <svg 
            id ='i' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" 
            fill="none" 
            viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
            stroke="currentColor">
        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z" />
        </svg></button>

        <button onClick={() => toggle(todo)}>
        <svg 
        id='i'
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" 
        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
         <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" />
    </svg>
        </button>

           </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

heres my form where im trying to get the data from upon submission. can anyone detect the issue?

```
        import { useState } from "react"
    import { db } from "../firebase"
    import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"
    
    const TodoForm = () => {
    
        const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
    
        const submitHandler = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            if(title !== "") {
                await addDoc(collection(db, "todos"), {
                    title,
                    completed: false
                })
                setTitle("")
            }
        }
    
        return (
            <div className="pt-80 flex justify-center flex-col items-center">
            <p className="font-bold sm:text-6xl">What Is There Todo?</p>
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="pt-5">
                <input 
                placeholder="Enter Todo..." 
                className="text-left w-60 border rounded px-4 py-2" 
                type="text" 
                value={title} 
                onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} required/>
                <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 ml-3 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" type="submit">Add Todo</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

import NavTodos from './components/NavTodos';
import TodoForm from './components/TodoForm';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './components/TodoItem';
import { collection, query, onSnapshot, updateDoc, doc, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from './firebase'

function App() {

  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState([])

  //fetch the data from firebase
  useEffect(() => {
    //query
    const qy = query(collection(db, 'todos'))
    //listens to document and creates shot w/ current contents. each time it changes the shot updates 
    const shot = onSnapshot(qy, (querySnapshot) => {
      let todoArr = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        todoArr.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
      })
      setNewTodo(todoArr)
    })
    return () => shot()
  }, [])

  const removeTodo = async (id) => {
    await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'todos', id))
  }

  const toggle = async (todo) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, 'todos', todo.id), {completed: !todo.completed})
  }

  const editTodo = async (todo, title ) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, 'todos', todo.id), {  title: title })
  }

  return (
    <>
    <NavTodos/>
    <TodoForm/>
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center pt-6'>
      {newTodo.map((todo) => (
        <TodoItem className ='list-none'
        key={todo.id}
        removeTodo={removeTodo}
        editTodo={editTodo}
        toggle={toggle}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where's that `todo` coming from? Is it a prop passed to this component? There's not enough code in your question for any kind of definitive answer.

Comment: My apologies. The code has been updated. Thank you for your response.

Comment: OK, so it's a prop. But where is that component used. How are properties passed? From the error you describe it appears that `todo` passed to this component is `undefined`.

Comment: OK, code is updated again

Comment: Now I see the problem -- you simply forgot to pass the `todo` prop to the `<TodoItem>` component.